# Add columns in vector but not in df

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to do the following and was wondering if there is an easier way to use dplyr to achieve this (I'm sure there is):

I want to compare the columns of a dataframe to a vector of names, and if the df does not contain a column corresponding to one of the names in the name vector, add that column to the df and populate its values with NAs.

E.g., in the MWE below:

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(c(1:6),c(11:16),c(10:15)))
colnames(df) <- c("A","B","C")
names <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
```

how do I use dplyr to create the two columns D and E (which are in names, but not in df) and populate it with NAs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need in `dplyr`, it's just a basic operation in base R. (Btw, try avoiding overriding built in functions such as `names` in the future. The reason `names` still works is because R looks in the base package NAMESPACE file instead in the global environment, but this is still a bad practice.)

```
df[setdiff(names, names(df))] <- NA
df
#   A  B  C  D  E
# 1 1 11 10 NA NA
# 2 2 12 11 NA NA
# 3 3 13 12 NA NA
# 4 4 14 13 NA NA
# 5 5 15 14 NA NA
# 6 6 16 15 NA NA
```